# How do I pull the selected items from a simple_list_item_multiple_choice with checkboxes?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to pull the items selected in a multiple checkbox `ListView` but `getcheckitempositions()` keeps returning null.

Relevant code:

Checkbox binding:

```
    final ListView list = (ListView) whoView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, friendList);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            CheckedTextView checkedTextView = ((CheckedTextView) view);
                            checkedTextView.setChecked(!checkedTextView.isChecked());
                        }
                    });
```

Trying to pull the items:

```
ListView list = (ListView) whoView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        List<String> invited = new ArrayList<String>();
        SparseBooleanArray checked;
        if (list != null) {
            checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions(); {
                for (int i = 0; i <= checked.size(); i++) {
                    if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
                        invited.add(list.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I suspect it has to do with the `getcheckitempositions()` pulling from the ListView and not the checkboxes, but I'm not sure how I would go about fixing this.

Comment: I think the issue might be that you are checking a TextView, not the actual list item

Comment: That was based on the code I found from a different quesiton.  I am trying to have checkboxes next to the list item.  That's probably why though.  Is there anyway I can bind them?  Set the list item checked when the TextView is?

Comment: You need to be using this method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked(int, boolean)

Comment: Where should I implement it?

Comment: In you onItemClickedListener